# How to add New slide in between existing slides in the Jquery Cycle Plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

While using the Jquery cycle plugin, I would like to able to insert slides dynamically in between existing slides and not just at the end.

This is the code I am using

```
function onBefore(curr, next, opts) {
  //Adding new slide
   opts.addSlide(item);

 //item has dynamic slide data which is going to added to the existing slides.
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can choose random effect in case you want to have random images order

Comment: I want to add dynamic slide data in between existing slides but using addslide() i'm able to add the slide data at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a slide in any position yo uwant, you just have to wait for the cycle to be on the slide before the one you need. This works quite well because you will add the slide just when you need to show it and in the position you want.

```
function onBefore(curr, next, opts) {

     // on the first pass, addSlide is undefined (plugin hasn't yet created the fn); 
     // when we're finshed adding slides we'll null it out again 
     if (!opts.addSlide)
        return;


    //add any type of logic here to make sure that you are in the position 
    //where you want to add your slide
    if ($(curr).index() === 8 && $(next).index() === 9) { 
       //Adding new slide
       opts.addSlide(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: I know how to addslide at the end with the help of addslide() but i'm asking about how can i add new slide at specific index?

Comment: this will add the slide exactly between slide 8 and slide 9. even if you have 15 slides in this clycle.

Comment: It's not working. New slide is getting added at the end only. Have a look at the JSfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/sqYAc/2/